# Check that there was an error one-liner in script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to put an error checking solution to my script, it looks like this:

```
! [ `echo $?` != 0 ] || echo "omg, st went wrong, CTRL+C? `read`"
```

My goal is when this line runs it check the "$?" - if it's not 0 then it says "omg, st went wrong, CTRL+C?" then it waits for enter, or CTRL+C from the user. But my one-liner isn't working, because it waits for an enter before printing the "omg, st went wrong, CTRL+C?" text. Can someone help me what am I missing?

Thanks.

UPDATE: it would be better to do it after the command st like in: [Check that there was an error one-liner in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14019/check-that-there-was-an-error-one-liner-in-script/14020#14020)

the "bad command" is "uname -k" the good command is "echo hi" - the uname gives non zero exit code, the echo gives 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct; the `` `read` `` will be performed and the result interpolated into the string sent to `echo`.

You're very much doing this the hard way, with all those interpolations and such.

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo -n 'command failed.  ^C or "q" to abort.'
    read c
    [[ "$c" == q ]] && exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

got the solution:

```
$ uname -k || echo 'omg, fail' || read
uname: invalid option -- 'k'
Try `uname --help' for more information.
omg, fail
$ echo hi || echo 'omg, fail' || read
hi
$
```

UPDATE: whoops, it doesn't waits for enter after printing the text :\

Comment: That doesn't work because the echo statement returns true. Try `uname -k || { echo 'omg, fail' && read; }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I write possibly long running scripts; I prefer to get a warning with a pop up. E.g. with zenity

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    if  zenity --question --text="Omg, something went wrong, do you wish to continue?"; then
    echo continue with program
    else
    echo "exiting" && exit; 
    fi
fi
```

This way I can do some other work and get notification if something breaks. Also, zenity info message is usually put at the end of script.